# Is numpy.polyfit with 1 degree of fitting, TLS or OLS?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two timeseries x and y, both have the same length. Using [numpy.polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html), I fit a straight line through the data with:

```
numpy.polyfit(x,y,1)
```

Is this [Total Least Squares (TLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) or [Ordinary Least Squares (OLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares)? I want to fit a TLS in python, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scipy.odr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) it will compute orthogonal regression which should be equal to tls.

Comment: Not having read the implementation of `scipy.odr` I cannot speak to its generality. However, I would caution that ODR is only a special case of TLS.