# Is scipy.odr computing total least squares or a special case of it?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017357/is-numpy-polyfit-with-1-degree-of-fitting-tls-or-ols/40017928) claims that [`scipy.odr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) should compute an [orthogonal regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression#Orthogonal_regression) and that it will be equal to the total least squares solution.

> You can use scipy.odr it will compute orthogonal regression which should be equal to tls.

However [Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) that both demming regression and orthogonal regression are special cases of total least squares.

> It is a generalization of Deming regression and also of orthogonal regression, and can be applied to both linear and non-linear models.

The [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html#r12d0b3321264-1) cites [*Orthogonal distance regression*](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Orthogonal-distance-regression-Boggs-Donaldson/57492e2500b031fb19c2986544cbf6dcd4dabe74) by Boggs and Donaldson 1989, which does not appear to mention total least squares.

Is using `scipy.odr` actually equivalent to this general case of total least squares?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/29935da21d5c34a197bf1ec91dd30f9e) is a related Python gist.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.odr`, which wraps the Fortran library ODRPACK, can solve a rather general form of the problem also known as "total least squares".

In *A stable and efficient algorithm for nonlinear orthogonal distance regression*, Boggs (the first author of most publications about ODRPACK) and coauthor write:

[image]

The TLS paper they refer to is by Golub and Van Loan, who wrote one of the [most influential papers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2156807.pdf?casa_token=ZglEsPQ0hDEAAAAA:BuV_Xslihzf7-xMHgaIFoG272Bz-NO2lQI3CfCFXpG57jZ4Mst8KrXnBd-TQT4zwD5pcBJbq6DD-O4qlu6OVB9uhc-KnO3Wf8t8BhvGAgxcnuhhXIw) on TLS.

[Searching](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22orthogonal%20distance%20regression%22%20AND%20%22total%20least%20squares%22&btnG=) for the two terms appearing in the same paper, there are several others that suggest that the "ODR" and "TLS" names alone cannot be used to distinguish between the techniques. For instance, Davis writes in *Total least-squares spiral curve fitting*:

[image]

What matters more than the name is exactly what generalizations you need. It looks like the referenced [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) states that TLS is a generalization of "Demming Regression" and "orthogonal regression" because the latter are for linear problems with one independent variable and one dependent variable, whereas TLS is generalized to multiple variables and nonlinear problems. So is `scipy.odr`/ODRPACK. The [ODRPACK User guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/external/odrpack_guide.pdf) and [`scipy.odr` API documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html) advertise support for:

- linear or nonlinear fitting functions;
- multiple independent and dependent variables or, more generally, multiple variables related implicitly; and
- weighting "to account for different variances of the observations, and even covariances between dimensions of the variables."

So although the answer may depend a bit on what you need, `scipy.odr` solves a pretty general form of this problem.